# Need explanation on this Java object initialization syntax

Tags: java, android, c++, syntax, object-initialization

I'm a `C\C++` programmer just starting on `Java`.

I came across this working Java snippet syntax that I understand what it does but I can't understand the logic of the syntax.

```
object x = new object
            .SetContent(aaa)
            .SetIcon(bbb)
            .SetText(ccc);
```

I get that the equivalent `C++` code is:

```
object* x = new object;

x->SetContent(aaa);
x->SetIcon(bbb);
x->SetText(ccc);
```

Can anyone explain to me the logic in the Java syntax?
Is this something like the Visual Basic's `With` Statement?

P.S.
Don't think it matters but the Java snippet is from an Android program.

Comment: [Method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#Java)

Comment: You can have the same syntax in C++ as well, just have the member functions return `this` and you can chain together the calls just the same.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg You mean `*this`, I assume :-)

Comment: @Spurdow: This is not the builder pattern.

Comment: @Angew It depends on *how* you want to chain it, with dot-syntax or with arrow-syntax. :)

Comment: @GabrielNegut I stand corrected, that was an eye opener. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Those chain calls are possible because each setter method returns a reference to `this`:

```
public object SetContent(final String input){
    this.aaa = input;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is [`method chaining in java`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561817/method-chaining-in-java), where each method returns the current instance so that you can invoke the next method on current returned object from that method.

Answer (score 0):

It's [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), where each method invocation returns the object it was invoked on.  It's very common to see in Java when creating an object with a `Builder`, e.g.

```
Foo foo = FooBuilder.builder()
    .setBar("bar")
    .setVolume(11)
    .setAnswer(42)
    .build();
```

Where each `.set___()` method returns the updated builder object, and the final `build()` call returns the actual `Foo` instance.  It would be perfectly equivalent to do this:

```
FooBuilder builder = FooBuilder.builder();
builder = builder.setBar("bar");
builder = builder.setVolume(11);
builder = builder.setAnswer(42);
Foo foo = builder.build();
```

But IMO the first version is much more readable.  I'm not much of a C++ guy but I think you can do the same thing there.

EDIT: Here's a real life example:
http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.Builder.html

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is creating the 'x' object, you should know that objects are references in Java.
this syntax is equivalent to:

```
private object x = new object();
x.setContent(aaa);
x.setIcon(bbb);
x.setText(ccc);
```

so first it create the object and then it calls each method.

Answer (score 0):

The instance of that `Object` is returned by each of the methods called,the next subsequent method uses that returned instance to operate further. This is internally done by returning `this` .

Example:

```
Object methodFirst(Object ob1)
{
ob1.doSomeOperations();
return this;
}

Object methodSecond(Object ob1)
{
ob1.doSomeOtherOperations();
return this;
}
```

the above methods can be called like :

```
Object newObject = oldObject.methodFirst().methodSecond();
```

A more comprehensive and deep explanation can be found [here](http://blog.lckymn.com/2009/06/30/method-chaining-to-use-or-not-to-use/)